# c# web api not working as POST Type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Below is my API structure

```
 public class CustomController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
    public DataSet POSTM(string StaffCode, string bytearray, string Reason)
   {
    //Some Business logic Here
   }
}
```

And its route

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi2",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{staffCode}/{bytearray}/{Reason}",
                defaults: new {
                    staffCode = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    bytearray = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    Reason = RouteParameter.Optional

                }
            );
```

I am try to invoke it from jquery ajax as

```
var data = {
            staffCode: staffCode_,
            bytearray: bytearray_,
            Reason: Reason_,
        };

        $.ajax(
            { url: 'http://localhost:59118/api/Custom/', 
             method : 'POST', 
             dataType: 'JSON', 
             data:data, 
             success: function (d) 
             { 
                 alert("Saved Successfully"); 

             }, 
             error: function (e) 
             { 
                 alert("Error please try again"); 
             } 
            });
```

After invoking it I am getting 500 Internal Server Error in console Log

But if I changed [HttpPost] to [HttpGet]  than it works perfectly fine

Why it is not working as POST ?

Comment: Change your parameter in the POST method to a model that contains those 3 properties. Note also only the last parameter in the route definition can be marked as `RouteParameter.Optional`

Comment: Changed parameter to model object and removed first two parameters from optional  but still show Internal Server Error

Comment: Then your server code is throwing an exception. And one issue is that you have `dataType: 'JSON',` but you method is clearly not returning JSON.

Comment: Ok , than why its work as GET service ?

Comment: Then debug your code (we cannot do it for you especially when you do not show it!). Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will contain the details of the error

Comment: @Jack, why are you returning DataSet from your controller method, when you are expecting 'JSON' in your ajax request? You should look after this

Comment: @alaa_sayegh , in MVC 5 the default encoding is json ,the data will be returned as json after conversion until unless you do not specify other return type and datatable or dataset are the perfect for this thing (to get json type key value )

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks

Comment: Do not completely change your question and invalid the answers and comments that have already been given (I have rolled back your changes). And I suggest you read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) to understand why you need a model for the POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave web api config route as it is by default

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then try call it like this

```
    var staffCode = "staff code here";
    var bytearray = "hell byte arry";
    var Reason = "no reason";

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:51524/api/Test/POSTM/',
            method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify([staffCode, bytearray, Reason]),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Saved Successfully");

            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error please try again");
            }
        });
```

controller look like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public DataSet POSTM(List<string> data)
    {
      //ur code here
    }
```

Receiving request from ajax 
[image]

Comment: This is not the best way as passing complex and lengthy data in URL is a limit which is not prefered.

Comment: @saif , it show error when we send an Base64 encded string from byte array , That's why I am sending it as object array

Comment: Tried but not running , maybe other methods in api class causing this issue

Comment: @Saif I tried the same , instead of list I am using model object . Its hitting the post method now but not posting values. values are passed as null

Comment: from where are you getting these values? can you please replace it with hard-coded values for test

Comment: Obviously I tried hard Coded values too, these values I am getting from textboxes

Comment: Got it , was missing contentType: "application/json",  It works now . How can I test in in google rest client extension ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `POST` and sending data in `body` then you need to bind model like this

```
[HttpPost]
public DataSet POSTM(MyModel model)
{
  //Some Business logic Here
}
```

and `MyModel` will be a class

```
public class MyModel 
{
  public string staffCode { get; set; }
  public string bytearray { get; set; }
  public string reason { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `[FromBody]` - that's the default

Comment: Still wont work - the model contains only fields, not properties :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just missed this one by mistake.

Comment: It does not work  .There are other methods too in api class , how it will work without modifying or creating route in WebApiConfig

Comment: Its Same 505: Internal Server Error , and still if I run it as get than no error

Comment: @Jack The issue seems to be with logic written, try putting debug point on Action and see that the model will be bind successfully.

Answer (score 0):

While you are sending data from Ajax,

Your attribute "`staffCode`" doesn't match with controller method attribute "`StaffCode`".

Attribute names are case sensitive.

Comment: No they are not. The model binder is not case sensitive

Comment: @Jack.. If you are using Models, please update your question. It will help you getting correct answers.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Updated